# horizontal stablity

Tags: table-making, stability

I'm making a table and I wonder if it will be horizontally stable.

Here are the details:
The table width is 160cm, depth 70cm, height 76cm.

The table top is 6cm thick and is made out of block-board (14mm pine core + 2mm birch + 1mm oak veneer). It's empty inside.

The table legs are 70cm tall and 70cm wide. They are made out of a stainless steel closed profile (width 4cm, depth 2cm, thickness 0.2cm).

I attach the drawing for clarity (all dimensions are in cm).
[image]

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

With kind regards,
Tomasz

Comment: What do you mean by "stable"? The weak point here is the place where the legs join the tabletop, and you haven't given us any details about that.

Comment: Related: http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5172/how-do-i-stop-the-table-i-built-from-wobbling-shaking-side-to-side

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the construction of the side panel/legs.  They are going to have to brace against lateral (side to side) movement as well as supporting the weight of the top.  Some pictures showing how they are constructed would help.

Comment: By being stable I mean if it does not wobble/move from left to right when I work on it e.g. during writing. The leg is connected to the table top by two screws. Additionally, a flat metal bar is welded to the leg and it is mounted to the table top by another two screws.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEggS.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEggS.jpg) Right now the entire connection is bad and hence the table top doesn't touch the leg nearly at all. There are only few touching points; even where the screws are, the table top doesn't touch the leg perfectly (I think the

Comment: I've posted a separate question like it was suggested.
Here you go http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/horizontal-stability-of-a-table

Comment: Thanks, closed this as a dupe of the other question you posted under your new user ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't put in aprons (which are one traditional way of providing some side support on the legs), and you can't put in other bracing members, all I can suggest is that you attach the leg extremely firmly (a good solid weld) to a larger plate so there is more leverage/support to prevent twisting. More screws, larger gauge screws, and screws specifically designed for the tabletop material, will help to strengthen that attachment.

If you do some searching on the web and look at designs of commercially made legs, that may give you some ideas on stronger designs. Or find a commercially made table that has the look you want and see how they solved it.